# Convertible's motor (likely) damaged

Tags: electrical, ford, mustang, water-leak

I own a 2013 Convertible Mustang. A couple of months ago, it had been raining heavily where I live. I started seeing water near the panel near the passenger seat whenever I'd drive. I was later told by my mechanic that the car's drains were clogged and the car had accumulated a lot of water.

Around the same time it had been raining, the convertible's roof stopped coming down and also the left rear window (the little one) stopped responding to the control and never comes down now.

I imagine the water must've damaged a motor (or potentially other electrical equipment) somewhere somehow. Ford dealership's quoting me $200 to merely look at the vehicle and figure what the problem is.

What do you guys suggest I do? Do I bite the bullet and go to Ford to get this checked/repaired? Should/can I go to a local body shop or something as a cheaper alternative?

Comment: The water may have caused a short and blown some fuses. Check the fuses and relay for the windows and drop top before you do anything else.

Comment: And find and clear the drains, or you'll be looking at the same failure(s) in the future.